# Why is the Fabry-Perot more accurate than Michelson?

Tags: optics, interferometry

> Why is the Fabry-Perot Interferometer on Na-lamp more accurate than Michelson Interferometer also on Na-lamp by counting the fringes of a circular pattern?

Comment: What are your ideas as to the answer to this question?

Comment: Have you ever seen the fringes of these instruments?

Comment: What effect do multiple reflections have on the fringe width?